# how to get the text of select options?

Tags: jquery

i have this code , and im currently getting the 'mytablevalues' but i wonder if i can get 'myvalues' , i mean only the text of the select.

```
 <form id="aform" method="post">
 <select id="menucompare" name ="menucompare" size="1">
<option value="nothing" <?php if ($menucompare == "nothing") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?>>Select one</option>

<option value="mytablevalue1" <?php   if ($menucompare == "mytablevalue1") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >myvalue1</option>
<option value="mytablevalue2" <?php   if ($menucompare == "mytablevalue2") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >myvalue2</option>
<option value="mytablevalue3" <?php   if ($menucompare == "mytablevalue3") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >myvalue3</option>
<option value="mytablevalue4" <?php if ($menucompare == "mytablevalue4") { echo " selected='selected'"; } ?> >myvalue4</option>


</select>
<input type="hidden" name="hidevalue" value="<?php echo $menucompare ;  ?>" />
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function() { 
         displayVals(); 
   });
   displayVals();
 });

function displayVals() {
var singleValues = $("#menucompare").val();
$("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);
$("p").html("Procent of :    " + singleValues);
}
```

and also im having trouble with default value (nothing).
any suggest !

EDIT .
 i get it to work like that

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("select").change(function() { 
         displayVals(); 
   });
   displayVals();
   });

  function displayVals() {
var singleValues = $("select option:selected").text();
$("#hiddenselect").val(singleValues);
$("p").html("Procent of : &nbsp &nbsp" + singleValues);
 }

</script>
```

Comment: You should post the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.text()` to get the text values of your options: http://api.jquery.com/text/

To get the text of the selected option you can use:

`$('#menucompare option:selected').text()`

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

**example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#menucompare").change(function() { 
     $("p").html("Procent of : " + $("option:selected", this).text());  
     $('input[name="hidevalue"]').val($("option:selected", this).text());  
   });

 });
</script>
```

`$('#hiddenSelect')` doesn't appear to exist in the example you posted, I've assumed that you're trying to set the value of the `input` with name `hidevalue`, I've included this change in the example above.

Another thing, there is no `<p>` in your example (unless you left it out?). I would suggest giving the `<p>` an `id` and select that to change it, otherwise the value of every single `<p>` on your page will be changed.

Comment: ph yes , i have the '<p>' in my code , this '<p>' is where to output the values . exemple i have it like that . '<?php echo "<p></p>"; ?>' and it output the values inside the p .

Comment: yes your code is loading the text normal but when jquery finish loading the text disapear .

Comment: did you remove your function `displayVals()` and any references to it? I can't see any other reason why this would happen, the values are only modified [in the example above] when the `select` is changed.

Comment: i removed all and replaced by your script

Comment: your code works ,when jquery is loading the text commes and when jequery is finished loading the text disapear .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuery to do that too, use this (for the example above)

```
$("#menucompare option:selected").text();
```

Comment: wow sorry was way too slow @ posting I guess didn't mean to offer the same exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the text of the selected option:

```
$('#menucompare').children("option[value='" + $('#menucompare').val() + "']").text();
```

Comment: u mean i replace all the script by this line ?